# Successfully installed Ubuntu but unable to load it in the system

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, boot

Process :

1. Inserted Ubuntu Bootable Pen Drive
2. Selected 3rd option i.e Something else
3. Than deleted  C drive (drive containing Windows)out of which I made 63GB unusable , created 15 GB ext4 - mount type / drive and installed Ubuntu in it and also had a separate swap area of 5 GB
4. Successfully installed the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

But now unable to load Ubuntu and Note Windows loader is still within the system and its showing  0xc000000f error during the boot. Unable to boot Windows 7 pen drive ( i.e after <kbd>F12</kbd> and getting Hard drive issues while running live Ubuntu as

> hard drive having health issues

With three button dialogue box : Examine , ok, cancel.

Now what I want?

Process: 2

1. Now with the help of Ubuntu Boot Repair tool I am done with booting/loading issues, but still disk utility shows hard drive health problem and says "hard disk failure is imminent"
2. As a result, I re-installed Ubuntu again, so during the re-installation of Ubuntu because of getting hard drive issues after getting rid of booting issue, I was recommended 2nd option from the dialog which gives you the option of installing the Ubuntu in three different ways as my system contains both Windows 7 and Ubuntu files ( Note : Windows 7 ( i.e C drive ) was intentionally deleted as said before. So as a result only some Windows loader files in the form of 105 MB system reserved drive is present).
3. After continuing with the 2nd option it takes whole hard drive as a partition to install the Ubuntu and below it shows that whole hard drive will formatted applying that action. Else I went with advanced partition option and proceeded with the 15Gb ext4 and mount type / kind of a partition to install Ubuntu, also device for boot loader installation was selected as that 105 MB system reserved Windows 7 loader drive, with this selection again was able to successfully install the Ubuntu.

Now what I want is to remove all the Windows 7 files from the system in a proper allowable way from the Ubuntu that I am able to boot now without formatting the whole hard disk and ultimately solve the hard drive health issues as shown in the snapshots.

Comment: Try Boot Repair from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Start afresh, In the given screen select option no 2

[image]